# Javascript and mobile functionality. Intermitant issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a small JavaScript setup for my mobile menu. On certain width media query, the menu moves to a side position. This behavior is on mobile devices, it doesn't occur in mobile emulation websites on my computer.

The issue is when I click the same menu item twice in a row, the menu disappears. I then have to lip phone horizontal and the reload page, it will work again.

heres my site: [my site](http://tangrm.com/)

```
var jPanelMenu = {};
    $(function() {
      $('pre').each(function(i, e) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
      });

      jPanelMenu = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: 'ul.sf-menu',
        animated: false,
        keyboardShortcuts: true
      });
      jPanelMenu.on();

      $(document).on('click', jPanelMenu.menu + ' li a', function(e) {
        if (jPanelMenu.isOpen() && $(e.target).attr('href').substring(0, 1) == '#') {
          jPanelMenu.close();
        }
      });

      $(document).on('touchend', '.menu-trigger', function(e) {
        jPanelMenu.triggerMenu();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });

      // Removes SuperFish Styles
      $('#jPanelMenu-menu').removeClass('sf-menu');
      $('#jPanelMenu-menu li ul').removeAttr('style');

    });
```

Curious if this is an issue with .removeClass or some other conlfict on the page.

Comment: Seems to work ok for me (Chrome). As you are using media queries, just resizing the browser window should be enough to test it. No need for "emulation".  Also, you should probably put the js in a Drupal behavior rather than a document.ready.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still experiencing issues with iphone6+ on safari. any other hints that could help?

Comment: I do not have an iphone to test on. You have an error on the page to do with ads but it may be nothing.

Comment: Thanks 2pha. It seems the Google ad was the conflict. Curious 1. How you found this error? 2. What's wrong with the ad code that's causing problems?

Comment: I found the error by looking in the console in chrome developer tools.